# Meteor.user() doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, meteor, meteor-accounts

I am trying to `console.log(Meteor.user().profile.group)`: But it causes the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'profile' of undefined

Using `Meteor.user()` alone returns undefined.

Here is the user details on Mongo:

```
{
        "_id" : "ccZztbFqw2MpgTsjX",
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-12-12T15:11:23.645Z"),
        "services" : {
                "password" : {
                        "bcrypt" : "$2a$10$lsYo7wjhA77.8TmNYeMTQ.u3jZzJSiIxsJrMRkjOPINHuLhBOENqm"
                }
        },
        "emails" : [
                {
                        "address" : "111@211.com",
                        "verified" : false
                }
        ],
        "profile" : {
                "name" : "11111",
                "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-12-12T15:11:23.558Z"),
                "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-12-12T15:11:23.558Z"),
                "group" : "user"
        }
}
```

Why `Meteor.user()` isn't working in Chrome?

**NOTE:** `Meteor.user().profile.group` prints the group to the console using Microsoft Edge browser

Comment: It works in Chrome, it just takes a few milliseconds to be loaded to the client. This problem comes up all the time.

Comment: @MichelFloyd your right, I put it inside a button and could print the group successfully. What is the best practice to delay its execution?

Comment: Depends on whether you're using Blaze or React.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works, but it takes a while when the user document is downloaded from the server.

When the app is loaded in your browser for the first time, Meteor.user() can be undefined.

What is your use case? If you want to access current user in the template, you can use [`currentUser`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html#currentUser) helper:

```
{{#if currentUser}}
    {{currentUser.profile.group}}
{{/if}}
```

If you call `Meteor.user()` from Chrome developer console, you can also see what's in it.

Answer (score -2):

Meteor does not expose the users collection by default (for your own good), if you want to control what is exposed and what isn't simply add a publish function for "userData".

Comment: the docs says "By default, the current user’s username, emails and profile  are published to the client". from here http://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html#Meteor-user